# Linq select only newest of duplicates

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have searched through posts but this is bugging me:
I am trying to remove duplicates from an XML and keep only newest:

The XML structure is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scanneditems>
  <item>
    <itemnumber>5701075006328</itemnumber>
    <description>Item 1</description>
    <timestamp>16-06-2017 10:40:39</timestamp>
   </item>
  <item>
    <itemnumber>5701075006328</itemnumber>
    <description>Item 1 duplicate</description>
    <timestamp>08-06-2017 14:25:51</timestamp>
   </item>
</scanneditems>
```

The code is:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\\fixthis.xml");

var item = xDoc.Element("scanneditems")
    .Elements("item")
    .GroupBy(c => c.Element("itemnumber").Value)

    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Elements("timestamp").ToString());

XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("scanneditems", item));
doc.Save("C:\\fixedfile.xml");
```

Problem: How do I limit result of each duplicate to newest?

Comment: I think you need to sort it correctly, by default this code will sort timestamps alphabetically. And then just call Distinct.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to take latest item from each duplicate.
So use `OrderBy..` inside grouped items

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\\fixthis.xml");
var items = 
    xDoc.Element("scanneditems")
        .Elements("item")
        .GroupBy(c => c.Element("itemnumber").Value)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Element("timestamp").Value).First());

var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("scanneditems", items));
doc.Save("C:\\fixedfile.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you  very much!
Exactly what I was looking for.